# Calculus: man jumping on a trampoline

Tags: calculus

A person is jumping straight up and down on a trampoline. The height of the centre of mass of the person is measured every tenth of a second. It takes just over one second to complete one full bounce.

```
t (seconds) 2.90 3.00 3.10 3.20 3.30 3.40 3.50 3.60 3.70 3.80 3.90 4.00 4.10 
x(t) (feet) 7.65 6.80 5.70 4.50 4.55 5.65 6.85 7.65 8.15 8.30 8.10 7.65 6.85
```

1. Find the average velocity (in feet/sec) of the jumper from 3.00 seconds to the time when he is at the lowest point. (If there is more than one lowest point in your data, compute the average velocity to the first "lowest point".)

I am not sure how to do it.

I am inclined towards forming an equation using $\sin$ or $\cos$.

the format of the equation is $k+a\,\cos(t)$
$k$ can be calculated using the data above.
$a$ which is the amplitude can be calculated using the maximum deviation from $k$.

BUT i am not sure ...

Comment: Are you _told_ in the problem statement to represent the height with a cosine function??? IMVHO when a person jumps on the trampoline, i.e. looses contact with it, the jump phase (which is actually a free fall) should be described with a quadratic function, and the bounce phase is a cosine-like (linear oscillator's half period).

Comment: There are very many ways to attack this problem. A first problem could be to estimate the time and height for the lowest point which is a problem of interpolation. As CiaPan writes a good model would probably have at least two parts, one free-fall part and one "trampoline resistance" part. Then calculating the times when those different ones come into effect is another not-so-obvious problem. It is a very good problem in that it taxes the students imagination.

Comment: @JacobManaker Four months later (referring to the comment you responded to), I honestly don't recall what I disliked about this textbook. I thought I recalled that the data did not fit a reasonable physical model, but now it seems they do fit a reasonable model (with some allowance for measurement errors). The question in the book is simple and direct and is answered below. Objection withdrawn.

Comment: @DavidK: Hah!  Those are good reasons to dislike a textbook.  Since we've achieved concord, I'll delete my comment too; but +1 for changing your mind so graciously.

Answer (score 2):

Given the following statement in your homework

> If there is more than one lowest point in your data, compute the average velocity to the first "lowest point

I would not try to fit a periodic function into the data, but rather explicitly take the point of lowest height from the given data. If the author of the question wants something different, he should have stated that.

Let $t_1$, $x_1$ be the values at $t=3.00s$.
And let $t_2$, $x_2$ be the point with lowest height.

Then the average speed is given by
$$\frac{Δx}{Δt} = \frac{x_2 -x_1}{t_2 - t_1}.$$

The curve $x(t)$ describes the location, and the quotient above describes the secant between $(t_1,x_1)$ and $(t_2,x_2)$.